# Selenium WebDriver and xpath: a more complicated selection

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver

So let's say my structure looks like this at some point:

```
..........
<td>
  [...]
  <input value="abcabc">
  [...]
</td>
[...]
<td></td>
[...]
<td>
  <input id="booboobooboo01">
  <div></div> <=======I want to click this!
</td>
.........
```

I need to click that div, but I need to be sure it's on the same line as the td containing the input with `value="abcabc"`. I also know that the div I need to click (which doesn't have id or any other relevant attribute I can use) is in a td at the same level as the first td, right after the input with id CONTAINING "boo" (dynamically generated, I only know the root part of the id). td's contain nothing relevant I can use.
This is what I tried as far as xpath goes:

```
//input[@value='abcabc']/../td/input[contains(@id,'boo')]/following-sibling::div

//input[@value='abcabc']/..//td/input[contains(@id,'boo')]/following-sibling::div
```

None of them worked, of course (element cannot be found).
I want to know if there's a way of selecting that div and how.

**EDIT: `//input[@value='abcabc']/../../td/input[contains(@id,'boo')]/following-sibling::div` is the correct way. This was suggested by the person with the accepted answer. Also note that he offered a slightly different way of doing it. See his answer for details.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
//input[@value='abcabc']/ancestor::tr[1]/td/input[contains(@id,'boo')]/following-sibling::div[1]
```

Note that `//input[@value='abcabc']/..` only goes up to the parent `<td>`, that's why your's did not work.

Comment: You are right, on both accounts: your way works, my way works also, with the added /... Thank you!

Comment: @Ameoo Just using `../../` is of course correct. I tend to use the more explicit `ancestor::tr[1]` because it requires less thinking when reading the code, but that's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

Another XPath that may work, is a bit more simple:

```
//input[@id='booboobooboo01']/../div[1]
```

Comment: :) there are more inputs with ids like 'booboo....'. I need to have an automation class which can manage any number of lines, and those lines have similar elements (for which I know the root part of the id, but not the rest of the id). Also, the values I have given for these ids and values are jsut random for this site. In normal operation, I am reading them from xml files, I don't really care what they are.